# TextInput non-functional on iOS with "Multitouch.mapTouchToMouse = false"?

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air

<sup>(Working with Flash Professional CC.)</sup>
I'm have an swf containing nothing but a TextInput and the following script in frame 1:

```
Multitouch.mapTouchToMouse = false;
Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT;
```

Publishing this swf for AIR 3.6 for iOS, the TextInput won't take the focus no matter how many times I tap it (it obviously works without `mapTouchToMouse = false`).

Is this a known issue and / or are there any workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

Is this a Flex TextInput? Regardless, the issue is most likely that the component relies on a `MouseEvent` to set the focus. Setting `mapTouchToMouse` to false means that all interactions fire a `TouchEvent` and not a `MouseEvent`. Setting it to true fires both. Other than a minor performance bump from not having to fire double the events, I can't think of any reason you would want to set this to false as there is no benefit whatsoever beyond that minor (likely unnoticeable) performance boost.

Also, from the live docs for [`Multitouch.mapTouchToMouse`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/ui/Multitouch.html#mapTouchToMouse):

> Setting this property to false can cause existing code, libraries, and frameworks that rely on mouse events to function incorrectly on devices that support touch input.

Comment: Sadly, I have a very good reason: It completely kills the "ButtonHitTesting" which has a major performance impact otherwise (profiled with Scout). If you have any idea on how to disable ButtonHitTesting otherwise, please do tell.

Comment: Interesting, I never even noticed that one before. Looks like it is taking up 6% of all active time in the app I am developing right now (as high as 50% in certain instances). You could attempt to roll your own TextInput component that relies on TouchEvent instead of MouseEvent

Comment: I even tried manually listening for `TOUCH_TAP` and `TOUCH_BEGIN` events on the textfield and then translating them to `mouseEvent`s (`MOUSE_DOWN` and `CLICK`) and dispatching those on the real TextInputs, but all to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by having a class that extends Textfield and in it's constructor I added a TouchEvent.TOUCH_TAP to it that looks like this:

```
private function onTap(event:TouchEvent):void{
    stage.focus = this;
    this.requestSoftKeyboard();
}
```

This will then mimic the behaviour of a normal textfield.